# XSLT selecting one of two nodes with same name based on attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XML Markup that looks like the following:

```
<pet type="dog" id="76">
</pet>
<pet type="cat" id="79">
</pet>
```

In this particular case, using XSLT - what's the most optimal way to create a variable to retrieve the cat and dog ids? The order is never the same so `/pet[1]` wouldn't work. It would have to be something such as:

```
<xsl:variable name="cat_id"><xsl:value-of select="...."/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="dog_id"><xsl:value-of select="...."/></xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Not an answer, just a note that you should generally avoid `<xsl:variable>` elements that contain nothing but a single `value-of` - it's more efficient to just use `<xsl:variable name="cat_id" select="...." />` instead because that avoids the need to create a text node and tree fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `<xsl:variable name="cat_id" select="//pet[@type = 'cat']/@id"/>` is the direct way, if you want efficient access define a key

```
<xsl:key name="pet-by-type" match="pet" use="@type"/>
```

and then use

```
<xsl:variable name="cat_id" select="key('pet-by-type', 'cat')/@id"/>
```

.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

```
<xsl:variable name="cat_id"><xsl:value-of select="pet[@type='cat']/@id "/ ></xsl:variable>
```

But it also depends on your actual position in input xml.